# Discord.py: forbidden 403, unable to send message to user - How do I get my bot to iterate through and dm all members in my server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am able to get the bot to direct message anyone with a specific role using the following code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_any_role(roleCheck)
async def dmrole(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, message):
    for member in ctx.message.server.members:
        if role in member.roles:
            await bot.send_message(member, message)
```

However, when I try to make the bot dm all users in my server, only I receive a message. This is the code I used:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_any_role(roleCheck)
async def dmall(ctx,*, message):
    for member in ctx.message.server.members:
        await bot.send_message(member, message)
```

When checking the output window, I get the error:

> "Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Cannot send messages to this
>   user"
>
> *Please note that there are various imports and variables defined outside of the code snippets shown here.

Any pointers as to where I am going wrong would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your bot may be missing the permissions it needs to be able to message the user.  Does it have the "manage role" permissions?

Comment: Yes, I have given it administrator perms and made sure that it was not a permission issue

Comment: thanks, that is a really good idea. will give that a try.

Comment: You will encounter FORBIDDEN if you attempt to direct message a user that has DMs disabled for non-friends. This is not a permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

So I found that simply catching and passing the exceptions was able to fix the error. Thanks for all your help.